# Using multiple conditional expressions within list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, list-comprehension

I am writing a program to `evaluate range(1, 10)` which should return `divisible by 3 and even` if a `number is divisible by 3 and even`.

If the the number is `even and not divisible by 3` then it should return `even`.

Otherwise it should return `odd`.

I need to use `list comprehension` to evaluate multiple `conditional expressions`.

My program looks as below:

```
l = list(zip(
            range(1, 10),
            ['even and divisible by 3' if x%3 == 0 else 'even' if x%2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(1, 10)]
             ))

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'odd'), (2, 'even'), (3, 'even and divisible by 3'), (4, 'even'), (5, 'odd'), (6, 'even and divisible by 3'), (7, 'odd'), (8, 'even'), (9, 'even and divisible by 3')]
```

I am not able to understand why program is giving `(3, 'even and divisible by 3')`. This is because, `x%2 == 0 else 'odd'` is evaluated first which should return `odd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different ways to group the expressions. Consider adding parentheses for clarity:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> 'even and divisible by 3' if x%3 == 0 else ('even' if x%2 == 0 else 'odd')
'even and divisible by 3'
>>> ('even and divisible by 3' if x%3 == 0 else 'even') if x%2 == 0 else 'odd'
'odd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to rewrite your list comprehension:

```
["even and divisible by 3" if x % 3 == 0 and x % 2 == 0 else "even" if x % 2 == 0 else "odd" for x in range(1, 10)]
```

Note that the first conditional checks both `x % 3` AND `x % 2`, then the second conditional checks only `x % 2`.

Answer (score 1):

For `x = 3`, since the first conditional is true, the expression evaluates to `'even and divisible by 3'` and then stops evaluating the rest of the conditionals.

You'd only want the first conditional to be true if it was the case that the number was divisible by both 2 and 3, so you're looking for the following:

```py
l = list(zip(
            range(1, 10),
            ['even and divisible by 3' if x%3 == 0 and x%2 == 0 else 'even' if x%2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(1, 10)]
             ))
```